# Todos won't show up from multiple \input{texdoc} documents

Tags: input, todonotes

I have split a paper into several .tex document chapters to input them in the main.tex document later. The problem is, the many `todo` notes I have made throughout my file are no longer showing up (worked fine when I was working out of just one long document). My file takes roughly this shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos

\input{chapter1}
.
.
.
\input{chaptern}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the pdf, I no longer get the `todo`s showing up. Has anyone encountered this? What could be the problem?

Comment: For information, to put your code in a special environnement in the site, select it with your mouse and press `Ctrl + k` `;-)`. Unfortunatly I can't help you for your question

Comment: The list of todo's is generated by `\listoftodos` - not `\listoftodonotes`. Then it worked in my case...